# NetworkX: How do I iteratively apply a network layout like spring_layout?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graph `G` and I want to layout the graph using the function

`node_positions=nx.spring_layout(G, iterations=5)`

However, I want to apply this function say 10 times and see how the layout changes with each application. Seems like every time I apply it, it starts from scratch giving me 10 layouts with 5 iterations each.

What I tried so far:

```
for i in range(10):
    node_positions=nx.spring_layout(G, iterations=5)            
    nx.set_node_attributes(G,'pos',node_positions)

    # draw network    
    plt.figure()
    ns = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=node_positions, node_color=node_colors, cmap = cm.PuRd, vmin=0, vmax = 0.035, node_size=70, alpha=.9)
    es = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=node_positions, alpha=.2, edge_color='#1a1a1a')

    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

I'd like to see how the spring layout works by visualizing its results every 5 iterations. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`spring_layout` takes an argument `pos` which serves as the initial condition.

So `pos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos= pos, iterations=5)` will work.  For the first time through, just set `pos=None`.

Comment: That does not work well, doing 10 iterations of that line will not result in a layout close to a single `iterations=50` run. Instead it gets stuck in a suboptimal state. No idea why, I guess some things get reset each time.